# Bootstrap, imgs have gaps in columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Right, I have a problem, I want to have four block images, that are 200px by 200px, to be in a row.

I want all four images to have no padding, so that they all are touching each other on the left and right sides.

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row top">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="img/1.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="img/2.jpg"width="200" height="200"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="img/4.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This result in padding on both sides. However if I delete the images and put classes on the columns that have a css property of height and width of 200px by 200px. They do what I want it to do.

Working sample with just background colors to see each box.
http://jsfiddle.net/bp9cwbp1/1/

How do I get the images to be touching each other like these four classes are?

Comment: but just added a class `.col-sm-3{display: inline-block;}` and it displays as your need

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/rLkf2w4d/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
}
```

Comment: If he needs to *have* the columns, it needs to remove the padding, added for the col-md-* classes of the divs, that can be done with  
`@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-fixed-200 {
        width:200px;
        padding:0px;
    }
}` If he doesn't, your solution is a clean, proper solution